# How can I rotate table in Pages?

Tags: macos

I hope somebody can help me. I have a table in pages and would like to rotate this by 90 degrees. When I select the table, the function "rotate" is not selectable. Is there a possibility ?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is exporting table as an image and inserting it to your document as an image object which is rotatable.